# Keeping track of initial value of linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Iterating through a linked list seems to be tricky for me sometimes (as I am learning).

I keep doing stuff recursively, but I want to do this one iteratively.

The next function adds the values from a list `l` to a list `mx`, if its value is greater than `x`:

```
typedef struct slist *Lint;

typedef struct slist {
    int value;
    Lint next;
} Nodo;

void split(Lint l, int x, Lint *mx){
    Lint mxtmp=NULL;

    while (l!=NULL){
        if(l->value > x){
            *mx = (Lint) calloc(1,sizeof(Nodo));
            (*mx)->value = l->value;
            (*mx)->next = NULL;
            mxtmp = *mx;
            *mx = (*mx)->next;
        }

        l = l->next;
    }

    *mx = mxtmp;

}
```

Printing `*mx` instead of a list gives me a single value (using a proper cycle to go through a list).

The thing is, it seems that I lose track of the start of a list; in this case, I can't seem to keep track of the pointer to the start of the list `*mx` , which is the list I am changing.

What should I do?

Another doubt I have about this function is, how could I not attribute the values to a new list, but instead make the new `mx` list, just point to the structs at the main list `l`?

Comment: Having two arguments, `Lint *mx` and `Lint *Mx`, which are so similarly named is asking for trouble.  As written, your code doesn't reference `Mx`, leaving me puzzled about what `Mx` might be intended for.  It isn't entirely clear what you want to do.  If you want to leave the list `l` unchanged but make a copy of any node from `l` where the value is greater than the threshold, then you do things one way — not too dissimilar from what you are doing now, in fact.  If you want to move the items from `l` to the list pointed at by `*mx`, then you have to do more work.

Comment: Also, what is the definition of the type `Lint`?  Is it a `typedef struct ListOfInt { ... } Lint;` or `typedef struct ListOfInt { … } *Lint;`?  You use `Lint mxtmp = NULL;` which suggests it is the second.  See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) which suggests that is not a good idea.

Comment: Removed the *Mx. I wanted to store something at my *mx list, but when i print, it prints only the last element

Comment: When `l->value` is greater than `x` you are moving away  and losing track of `*mx` by assigning a newly allocated memory to it.

Comment: You should really consider using more meaningful names for your variables

Comment: Having the node pointer type makes your code less readable. Don't do that! You can create a (recursive) pointer to the incomplete struct the same as for the typedef of LInt (which is btw. also a bad choice for a pointer type). Also: why not return the new list instead of passing a `**` to the function? In general, it is better to return a value than to pass a pointer to a variable. This is actually a hack if there is more than one result to return (e.g. value and error-code) and should be best avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Diagnosis

Your problem is in this code:

```
void split(Lint l, int x, Lint *mx){
    Lint mxtmp=NULL;

    while (l!=NULL){
        if(l->value > x){
            *mx = (Lint) calloc(1,sizeof(Nodo));
```

Your assignment to `*mx` means you've lost your original pointer, and can't update your list properly.  There are few platforms where using `calloc()` won't set the pointer to null, but there's no point in using `calloc()` when your code explicitly sets the content of the structure.

You probably need something more like:

```
void split(Lint l, int x, Lint *mx)
{
    Lint mxtmp = NULL;

    while (l != NULL)
    {
        if (l->value > x)
        {
            mxtmp = (Lint) malloc(sizeof(*mxtmp));
            if (mxtmp == 0)
                …report error and do not continue…
            mxtmp->value = l->value;
            mxtmp->next = *mx;
            *mx = mxtmp;
        }
        l = l->next;
    }
}
```

This inserts the items on `*mx` in the reverse of the order that they appeared in `l` because it always inserts at the front of the list.  You can arrange to append to the end of the `*mx` if you prefer.

If you need to remove entries from the source list, `l`, and transfer them to `*mx`, then you need to pass `Lint *l` to the function so that the head of the list can be updated if the first item in `l` (or `*l` with the revised signature) needs to be transferred to `*mx`.

#### Explanation

> This does the job very well. Do you mind explaining what happens with the `*mx`? Because I don't seem to understand how the `*mx` is "increased"; it seems that the `*mx` is always in the same pointer value.

I'm relieved it works because I hadn't had a chance to test it before this update.

Let's suppose we're given a call like this:

```
Lint list1 = 0;
…populate list1…
Lint list2 = 0;
split(list1, 10, &list2);
```

The pointer `list2` has its own address.  It holds a value, initially the null pointer.  The address of the `list2` pointer is passed to `split()`, which means that `split()` can modify the pointer contents (just like if you have `int i = 0; some_func(&i);`, then `some_func()` can modify the value in `i`).

As `split()` traverses the list, `l`, when it finds a value that needs to be copied, it creates a new node pointed at by `mxtmp`, and fills in the value.  It makes the new node's `next` pointer point to what is currently at the head of the list (`mxtmp->next = *mx;`), then it modifies the address that `*mx` — which is effectively `list1` in the calling function in the example call — points at so that it contains the address of the new node (`*mx = mxtmp;`).

#### Testing

This is the test code I came up with, which runs cleanly under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct slist *Lint;

typedef struct slist
{
    int value;
    Lint next;
} Nodo;

static void error(const char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static void split(Lint l, int x, Lint *mx)
{
    // Note minor change compared to original suggested code.
    while (l != NULL)
    {
        if (l->value > x)
        {
            Lint mxtmp = (Lint) malloc(sizeof(*mxtmp));
            if (mxtmp == 0)
                error("Out of memory");
            mxtmp->value = l->value;
            mxtmp->next = *mx;
            *mx = mxtmp;
        }
        l = l->next;
    }
}

static void print_list(const char *tag, Lint list)
{
    printf("%s:", tag);
    while (list != NULL)
    {
        printf(" --> %d", list->value);
        list = list->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

static void insert(Lint *list, int value)
{
    Lint node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node == 0)
        error("Out of memory");
    node->value = value;
    node->next = *list;
    *list = node;
}

static void destroy(Lint list)
{
    while (list != NULL)
    {
        Lint next = list->next;
        free(list);
        list = next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Lint list1 = NULL;
    insert(&list1, 2);
    insert(&list1, 10);
    insert(&list1, 11);
    insert(&list1, 23);
    print_list("List 1", list1);

    Lint list2 = NULL;
    split(list1, 10, &list2);
    print_list("List 1", list1);
    print_list("List 2", list2);

    destroy(list1);
    destroy(list2);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Compilation

The source file was called `nodo.c`, so the program was called `nodo`, and I have a `makefile` configured with lots of compiler warning options enabled.  There were no warnings (from GCC 5.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.10.3):

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror nodo.c -o nodo
$
```

I regard that as about the bare minimum requirement; I don't usually even run the code until it compiles that quietly.

#### Example output:

```
List 1: --> 23 --> 11 --> 10 --> 2
List 1: --> 23 --> 11 --> 10 --> 2
List 2: --> 11 --> 23
```

Printing `list1` twice is paranoia, checking that it was not damaged during the `split` operation.  Note that the `split()` function should be written to use the `insert()` function.

A debugging print would also print the addresses of the node and the next pointer:

```
static void print_list(const char *tag, Lint list)
{
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    while (list != NULL)
    {
        printf("--> %3d  (%p, next %p)\n", list->value, (void *)list, (void *)list->next);
        list = list->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Yielding, for example:

```
List 1:
-->  23  (0x10081f410, next 0x10081f3c0)
-->  11  (0x10081f3c0, next 0x10081f370)
-->  10  (0x10081f370, next 0x10081f320)
-->   2  (0x10081f320, next 0x0)

List 1:
-->  23  (0x10081f410, next 0x10081f3c0)
-->  11  (0x10081f3c0, next 0x10081f370)
-->  10  (0x10081f370, next 0x10081f320)
-->   2  (0x10081f320, next 0x0)

List 2:
-->  11  (0x10081f4b0, next 0x10081f460)
-->  23  (0x10081f460, next 0x0)
```

#### Parting comments

I didn't reorganize the data types, but left to my own devices I would probably have used something like:

```
typedef struct List List;
struct List
{
    int   value;
    List *next;
};
```

And then passed `List *` and `List **` around.  This uses the tag name as the type name, which is something C++ does automatically without the explicit `typedef`.

Comment: This does the job very well. Do you mind explaining what happens with the *mx? Because i don't seem to understand how the *mx is "increased", it seems that the *mx is always in the same pointer value.

Comment: See the new 'Explanation' section in particular.

Comment: and that is an explanation! Can't thank you enough. Got it clear as crystal man :)

Comment: For what i've read, this technique to fill up a linked list is called "inchworm" ?

Comment: Maybe: a Google search for 'inchworm linked list' certainly shows that _inchworm_ is used as a term for this, but it wasn't one I'd come across before.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct slist *Lint;

typedef struct slist {
    int value;
    Lint next;
    } Nodo;

void split(Lint l, int x, Lint *mx){
     Lint mxtmp=NULL;
     int i = 0;
     while (l!=NULL){
         if(l->value > x){
             *mx = (Lint) calloc(1,sizeof(Nodo));
             (*mx)->value = l->value;
             (*mx)->next = NULL;
             if(!i) //mxtmp will keep track of the first allocated Nodo item
             {
               mxtmp = *mx;
               i++;
             }
             mx = &((*mx)->next); // with this, next( so *mx) will be initialized to point to a new Nodo item in the next loop
         }

         l = l->next;
     }

     mx = &mxtmp; //finally we make mx point to the first allocated Nodo item
}
```

I did the following code to test it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct slist *Lint;

typedef struct slist {
    int value;
    Lint next;
    } Nodo;

void recurs_free(Lint f)
{
   if(!f)return;
   if(f->next)recurs_free(f->next);
   free(f);
}

void recurs_printf(Lint f)
{
   if(!f)return;
   printf("%d\n", f->value);
   if(f->next)recurs_printf(f->next);
}

void split(Lint l, int x, Lint *mx){
     Lint mxtmp=NULL;
     int i = 0;
     while (l!=NULL){
         if(l->value > x){
             *mx = (Lint) calloc(1,sizeof(Nodo));
             (*mx)->value = l->value;
             (*mx)->next = NULL;
             if(!i) //mxtmp will keep track of the first allocated Nodo item
             {
               mxtmp = *mx;
               i++;
             }
             mx = &((*mx)->next); // with this, next( so *mx) will be initialized to point to a new Nodo item in the next loop
         }

         l = l->next;
     }
     mx = &mxtmp; //finally we make mx point to the first allocated Nodo item
}

int main()
{
    void recurs_printf(Lint f);
    void recurs_free(Lint f);
    void split(Lint l, int x, Lint *mx);
    Lint t = NULL;
    Nodo a = {1, NULL}, b = {2, &a}, c = {3, &b}, d = {4, &c}, e = {5, &d};
    split(&e, 3, &t);
    recurs_printf(t);
    recurs_free(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in fact it changed something but he need to get the first item of the single linked list so mxtmp has to be initialized once and return to mx at the end

Comment: Note that you can remove both `i` and `mxtmp` from your code in `split()` and the function behaves the same externally: `void split(Lint l, int x, Lint *mx){
     while (l!=NULL){
         if(l->value > x){
             *mx = (Lint) calloc(1,sizeof(Nodo));
             (*mx)->value = l->value;
             (*mx)->next = NULL;
             mx = &((*mx)->next);
         }
         l = l->next;
     }
}`

Comment: Thank you very much , this was more of what i was searching for! Makes total sense that i put inside mx variable, the address thus the content of the thing pointed by that variable isn't immediately changed.  I am divided, both answers are great :( .